# How do I atomically move a 64bit value in x86 ASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, thread-safety, atomic

First, I found this question: [How do I atomically read a value in x86 ASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349859/how-do-i-atomically-read-a-value-in-x86-asm)
But its a bit different, in my case I want to atomically assign a float (64bit double) value in a 32bit application.

From: "Intel® 64 and IA-32 ArchitecturesSoftware Developer’s Manual, Volume3A"

> The Pentium processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following additional memory operations will always be carried out atomically:
>
> Reading or writing a quadword aligned on a 64-bit boundary

Is it actually possible using some assembly trick?

Comment: Hint: read up on memory barrier/memory fence. Btw; why is this question tagged "c++"?

Comment: Are you asking how you get the quadword suitably aligned in memory or are you asking how to store a quadword in memory?

Comment: I need each operation to be made atomic.  I dont care If the value is changed between I read it and write it, but I want `a = b;` that a always contains a correct value of any state of the b value

Comment: The only "trick" is that the read and write need to be 64bit, so you can use x87 instructions or MMX instructions or SSE instructions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 64-bit x86 asm, you can use integer `mov rax, [rsi]`, or x87 or SSE2.  [As long as the address is 8-byte aligned (or on Intel P6 and later CPUs: doesn't cross a cache-line boundary) the load or store will be atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86).

Note that the common baseline across AMD and Intel is still only 8-byte aligned; *only* Intel guarantees atomicity for a cacheable load that's misaligned but not split across cache lines.  (AMD may guarantee something with a wider boundary, or at least do that in practice for some later CPUs).

---

In 32-bit x86 asm, your only option using only integer registers is `lock cmpxchg8b`, but that sucks for a pure-load or pure-store.  (You can use it as a load by setting expected=desired = 0, except on read-only memory though).  (gcc/clang use `lock cmpxchg16b` for `atomic<struct_16_bytes>` in 64-bit mode, but some compilers simply choose to make 16-byte objects not lock-free.)

So the answer is: **don't use integer regs**: `fild qword` / `fistp qword` can copy any bit-pattern without changing it.  (As long as the x87 precision control is set to full 64-bit mantissa).  This is atomic for aligned addresses on Pentium and later.

On a modern x86, use SSE2 `movq` load or store.  e.g.

```
; atomically store edx:eax to qword [edi], assuming [edi] is 8-byte aligned
movd   xmm0, eax
pinsrd xmm0, edx            ; SSE4.1
movq   [edi], xmm0
```

With only SSE1 available, use `movlps`.  (For loads, you may want to break the false-dependency on the old value of the xmm register with `xorps`).

With MMX, `movq` to/from `mm0-7` works.

---

**gcc** uses SSE2 `movq`, SSE1 `movlps`, or x87 `fild`/`fstp` in that order of preference for `std::atomic<int64_t>` in 32-bit mode.  Clang `-m32` unfortunately uses `lock cmpxchg8b` even when SSE2 is available: [LLVM bug 33109](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33109).  .

Some versions of gcc are configured so that `-msse2` is on by default even with `-m32` (in which case you could use `-mno-sse2` or `-march=i486` to see what gcc does without it).

**I put [load and store functions on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYRYkAtgW7zcXAAwBBcxeFFMIEHvSHj2pug7r3HLbnXCkFlJsTC0BS2sAN3QCTH8SYIhvYC8PFJYASk0AdnCLdQL1AHoi9RZBenUSePQAB3UMfVqCJmxSYXUAM1JndRoxW1SWQk8iJGwy0hTu3v1sfTIAT2tC4tKxNlbhDrHsRfUBiYBlI9wedQAFCwARa4BFFcKAoJCAOlsybAhy/kZ4%2BxAcwWpEWAH0yDhSKDgqwAB4hDJhaxcbLXZERSzJVKedzDCDRWJZFF5VbBIgSNj%2BQLBTCvXGYCC2AFApbg0iQ6HYOEIpERVHoiwyDLMWQAVhk5DYsjMEvQsm0gkE/nEkgmCnoEqI0qFwoA1iB5PJXgA2AAcAE55GYrdlRaazNlzaaRTIACwS/QgUVmSXa8hymQS4QgH1amQy4VwWAoRrNVoUKgQWMtNogYDZHjkTotIhtYMQABGfoLSiCi1kGvIjTmbCIAHlNuXwxKcPp2MBWn7CMFUEQCJFsMHm%2BRsPDUGJcxWJUpc0w/URSARPTINcLWBw0Ir%2BMwCAXg5BhXU%2Bx4hwBaOvydSn/Tyc5XgDqLCYTCv%2BnJbGwWmugWEAHcuUwQYqlIDBrmKEpSsOAawqaxqnsarrqMAqCoOo2SvOcED4MQZCaDw8h/Nozhxm0eHyKKGSatqGTCuMwyphAYFuh6Xo%2BpBMr%2BrIQYhuQYYRnqBpGmalrWg6doOk6LryBBfoBlRzaRogUbIGgxEpgm1DJvGaYZlmOZ5tQRbDiWbBllOVbODW9aNl28ztp2w7dtgvb9oOfqjs5E7SCu061ly86Lsuq7MO2m78IIO57vAh61MebBnher63gUp6Ps%2Br7bBM17vp%2B8jfiwf4AUBEggfQTHir6UGyDBcEIUhKFoRh6hYYQCRkYRanxu1lG8dRAnyK6rwZhmZjmtk9DyOaE30Iwc7MeQnrepVHFySIPF8UK5DKRAMadW0lCaXtpA6Zm2ZMLm7SGcWpYguZ1bYLWDZME2HGtvZ3mvQQPZ9gOQ4cR546Tj5lB%2BXNHELkuU5rqF3DhduTC7vujH%2BrFBAnrI56XteyUPk%2BL7XiwkSwq%2BOVfj%2B/7PsVqqgS6FXsbK1WwfBiHIah6GYdhbXquQ6hEU06lka6PUbTR5B0ZC1BMe6C2sctDOBmtoZ9eQ%2BoDUNPAjWNE1TQRs2yNJcucQrItbUpSm7fz8YHUmR0gEYqD0M6Z0XfmRkcSZZnA/dj02Y5dkcA5n3fa5f0SgDXnmTO/nDhDQWbeunBbkICNRQeKNxQlWM3jwVOleVMlVTINXM%2Bo9vqI7zWc7h3O80dZHyMLyv6vhrxmBroqWvI2STbarrGtkLrS4tbGyVxiu9QppvwDtqmW/tiZaamKjtq6ZiMM7BmFtdpm3V7lkPdZz22W2AcfS2X3OT9bnDuHQOVlHYOaoFUMhRusMCPDiPRenaPxRjiWniZCnL8Kd35Kmxuca8mUc4iGAtIMqtMC4rUZrVRCy9PCDTMK8SoLUcKkHajzPmJF8EKB4I3BStFsD0WOsjOaQ9Zb0yNtxJWFCVYGnoK8O0A1TQZnoG3bIFoeCiikkg%2BW8l%2BIuhgYw1aIthQDnaL/EArogA) to see asm from gcc with x87, SSE, and SSE2.  And from clang4.0.1 and ICC18.**

gcc bounces through memory as part of int->xmm or xmm->int, even when SSE4 (`pinsrd` / `pextrd`) is available.  This is a missed-optimization ([gcc bug 80833](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80833)).  In 64-bit mode it favours ALU movd + pinsrd / pextrd with `-mtune=intel` or `-mtune=haswell`, but apparently not in 32-bit mode or not for this use-case (64-bit integers in XMM instead of proper vectorization).  Anyway, remember that only the load or store from `atomic<long long> shared` has to be atomic, the other loads/stores to the stack are private.

---

**In MSVC**, there's an **`__iso_volatile_load64`** intrinsic in later versions of Visual C++ 2019 that can compile to an appropriate sequence of instructions.

Comment: For storing, it emits a `cmpxchg8b` loop though.  At least the last time I tested.

Comment: @fuz: you were probably looking at clang, which unfortunately does that.  Or you were looking at a RWM operation, not a pure-load or pure-store.  Updated the answer with a godbolt link.