# x64: Concurrent writes to bool array

Tags: c, memory, x86, 64-bit, volatile

Assuming I have an array like this in C:

```
static volatile bool my_array[128] = {0};
```

And on top of that I have 128 threads and each thread writes to a *different* index `true` whenever it is finished.

Can this produce some issues? Writing a single byte has no impact to the surrounding bytes on x64, right?

I'm just asking, because I'm not sure if the CPU / memory controller / etc. always reads 8 (or 4) bytes and then writes them. Which would create some weird race condition.

Thanks a lot

Comment: As long as each thread only writes to its specific index, it's all okay. With that said, 128 treads might be a little too much.

Comment: Oh, and `volatile` is not a synchronization keyword.

Comment: Related: [Why is volatile not considered useful in multithreaded C or C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2484980/12149471)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I disagree with your first comment. If one thread reads from all `my_array` elements in order to determine whether all threads are finished, while other threads are possibly still writing to `my_array` and there is no thread synchronization in between, then the behavior is undefined and it can also cause trouble in practice.

Comment: So is the actual question here if x86_64 guarantees atomic access for an 8 bit read-modify-write? That's the compiler's business to handle.

Comment: Maybe this answers the question? [How do I atomically move a 64bit value in x86 ASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046591/how-do-i-atomically-move-a-64bit-value-in-x86-asm)

Comment: For the reasons stated above, it would probably be better to use `atomic_bool` or [`atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag) instead of `volatile bool`, which both require `#include <stdatomic.h>`.

Comment: I'd imagine that from the abstract machine perspective it should not be a problem. Each array element is considered a separate object. So how it is implemented under the hood - it's the compiler's problem.

Comment: The notes for the description of [memory location](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.14) in the C specification clarify matters.

Comment: Use `std::atomic<bool> my_array[128]` with `memory_order_relaxed` to get the same semantics as `volatile` (in real compilers that do define the behaviour, which was how pre-C++11 programs could do lock-free code.)  But probably you want `memory_order_release` so readers can sync-with the thread and safely read other results it's written.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, x86-64 guarantees that byte stores and loads are thread-safe, not disturbing surrounding bytes.  All ISAs that provide byte stores in hardware at all give the same guarantee.  The Q&A you linked about 64-bit loads appears unrelated, it's about how wide an atomic load or store can be. The relevant one is [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721075) (yes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No two elements of the array are stored in the same *memory location* as defined by the C standard, so concurrent access or modification of separate elements of the array do not interfere with each other, as confirmed by C17 3.14 paragraph 2:

> **3.14**
>
> 1. **memory location**
>
>    either an object of scalar type, or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width
> 2. **Note 1 to entry**: Two threads of execution can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each
>    other.

The only thing to be careful of is the concurrent update of different bit-field members in a sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width, as confirmed by the next paragraph of C17 3.14:

> 3. **Note 2 to entry**: A bit-field and an adjacent non-bit-field member are in separate memory locations. The same applies to two bit-fields, if one is declared inside a nested structure declaration and the other is not, or if the two are separated by a zero-length bit-field declaration, or if they are separated by a non-bit-field member declaration. **It is not safe to concurrently update two non-atomic bit-fields in the same structure if all members declared between them are also (nonzero-length) bit-fields, no matter what the sizes of those intervening bit-fields happen to be.**

(emphasis mine).

The next paragraph of C17 3.14 provides an example:

> 4. **EXAMPLE** A structure declared as
>
>    ```c
>    struct {
>          char a;
>          int b:5, c:11,:0, d:8;
>          struct { int ee:8; } e;
>    }
>    ```
>
>    contains four separate memory locations: The member **`a`**, and bit-fields **`d`** and **`e.ee`** are each separate memory locations, and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields **`b`** and **`c`** together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields **`b`** and **`c`** cannot be concurrently modified, but **`b`** and **`a`**, for example, can be.

---

**NOTE**

I speculate that concurrent access to different elements of a "packed" array, or to different members of a packed structure is potentially unsafe on some architectures, but that is outside the scope of the C specification.

Comment: Yes, C++ `std::vector<bool>` packs bits densely, which makes it unsafe to write separate indices from separate threads.  (And the iterators aren't just pointers; it's messy and [a bad/surprising name for a good data structure](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).)

Comment: An equivalent Q&A for C++ is [C++ memory model and race conditions on char arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19903338) - char and bool must each be wide enough for the machine to be able to access without disturbing surrounding elements.  Typically 1 byte.  And re: the OP's concern about hardware doing wider reads/writes: despite misconceptions / FUD, all modern ISAs (except for DEC Alpha) do have safe byte loads/stores, including but not limited to x86: [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46721075)

Comment: For performance, you'll still have false sharing between all 64 threads whose bool shares a cache line.  If they finish at slightly separate times, this is fine, and makes it faster to collect the results and check that they're all `1`.  But if you're resetting to 0 and handing new work to different threads, might be better to spread this out more like with `std::atomic<int> elements (typically 4 bytes, a reasonable tradeoff of 16 threads sharing a 64-byte cache line.)